# Looping on magento success order message

Tags: php, magento

Dears I'm facing a looping problemn on magento success order message. The block is rendered many times until the system gets exausted in memory.

Do you have any tip where I can search for the bug ?

Magento 1.8.1 / Ultimo Theme / PHP54 / Amazon Linux

Comment: may be the code is running in foreach loop.. not sure where exactly though. If you provide some code where you had made changes then may be you will get answer here.

Comment: Yes Mr_Green I believe also that the problemn is a foreach looping. But the point is that I don't know which magento file I should analyse. I noticed that the success.phtml is rendered until infinite. The point is that I don't know which file renders this block.